# MSVC remove section from binary

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

In my code, I have a special section and some data in it:

```
#pragma section("dead",read,discard)
__declspec(allocate("dead"))
static const char dead_str[] = "DEAD";

doSomething(dead_str);
```

That section may or may not be loaded with the program, but is still part of the binary image. What I want to do is completely remove it from the image so it's guaranteed to not be loaded, and so that it cannot be found in the binary. Basically, I want:

```
strings myprogram.exe | grep DEAD
```

to have no hits. I'm fine with the program crashing when I try to reference the string.

In GNU, I'd do:

```
objcopy --remove-section=dead myprogram.exe
```

and Cygwin's `objcopy` actually does that, but corrupts the executable so it can no longer load. `editbin.exe` from MSVC can just change the flags for the section, but it stays in the image. And linker optimizations will not remove `dead_str` because it is referenced in `doSomething()`.

Is there some way (ideally as a linker flag) I can remove an entire section from PE/COFF files?

Comment: It seems that MSVC treats the output PE/COFF binary as the result of linking and no official tools are provided yet to perform a change of PE structure without relinking the program. What editbin.exe provides are mostly inplace changes.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for a linker setting too, but it seems this is not possible at all with MSVC.
What you can do is either writing your own tool to strip sections from PE files, or use CFF Explorer for example.